# How to rotate HTML5 Canvas' background image and also Zoom in & out using a slider?

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

I'm a beginner at coding. I want to do these things:

1. Create A Canvas.
2. Put some background image. Please note that I want a background image only. I don't want to keep image in foreground using 'drawImage(image, x, y)'.
3. Keep a slider that can be used to zoom-in and zoom-out the background image. (The problem here is that if I keep the image in background, I don't know how to catch it, so that I can re-size it).
4. Keep two buttons. One to rotate the image left and Second button to rotate the image right.

I want to do these things using HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery only.

I'd appreciate if someone can explain me something that is easy for a beginner to understand. If possible, please explain the code in details.

Thank You.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
    <div class="slider" style="width:500px; height:10px;"></div>
        <br />

        <div id="div_buttons">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="rotateLeft" align = "left" value="Rotate Left" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="rotateRight" align = "left" value="Rotate Right" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    <!--HERE IS THE STYLE TAG... -->
    <style type="text/css">
        img
        {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .canvas
        {
            background: url('script.jpg');
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>

    <!--HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT INSIDE <SCRIPT> TAG... -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var globalElement_width;
        var globalElement_height;

        $(document).ready
        (function() {
            $img = $('.canvas img');
                globalElement_width = $img.width();
                globalElement_height = $img.height();

                $(".slider").slider
            ({
                        step: 1,
                        min: 10,
                        max: 100,
                        value: 0,
                        slide: function(event, ui)
                            {
                                resize_img(ui.value);
                            }
                });

                //$('.canvas img').draggable();

                $("#rotateLeft").click(function() { 
                    $('canvas').css({
                                "transform":"rotate(-90deg)"
                                });
                    }
                ) //addClass("left")

                $("#rotateRight").click(function() {

                    $('canvas').css({
                                "transform":"rotate(0deg)"
                                });
                    }
                )
            });

            function resize_img(val) 
        {
            var width = globalElement_width;
            var height = globalElement_height;
            var zoom_percen = (height * 1); // Maximum zoom 50%
            var ASPECT = 10;//zoom_percen / 30;
            var zoom_value = val / 1;
            var size = width + ASPECT * zoom_value;
            var d = ASPECT*zoom_value/10;          

            $img = $('.canvas img');
            $img.stop(true).animate({
            marginTop: -d,
            marginLeft: -d,
            width: size,
            height: size
            }, 250);
        }

    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: If you have started please share your code.

Comment: @user2063661: Please put all of your code in the question, so it will be easily understandable.

Comment: @Digvijay Yadav: It is not allowing me to paste my entire code in comment window. Is there any other way possible to share the code here?

Comment: @user2063661: Have you tried the scale method of the context object.
I guess that will solve the zoom problem

Comment: @user2063661: Not in the comment. Put it in your question. You can find the edit button just below your question.

Comment: @Digvijay Yadav: Thank You. I was not knowing that I can re-edit the question. I've pasted entire code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer to my own question. The code is working nicely. Only facing problem while rotating the image & a bit with zooming.

Here is the code:

```
        <div id="div_buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 580px;">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="rotateLeft" align = "left" value="Rotate Left" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="rotateRight" align = "left" value="Rotate Right" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="result" style="position: absolute; top: 520px;" >Here is the div</div>

    <!--HERE IS THE STYLE TAG... -->
    <style type="text/css">
        img
        {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .canvas
        {
            background: url('sky.jpg') no-repeat 30% 30%;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            repeat: false;
            opacity: 0.5;
            repeat: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!--HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT INSIDE <SCRIPT> TAG... -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var globalElement_width;
        var globalElement_height;
        var newangle = 0;
        var operation = "";

        $(document).ready
        (function() {
            $img = $('.canvas');
                globalElement_width = $img.width();
                globalElement_height = $img.height();

                $(".slider").slider
            ({
                        step: 1,
                        min: 1,
                        max: 100,
                        value: 0,
                        slide: function(event, ui)
                            {
                                resize_img(ui.value);
                            }
                });



                //THIS IS THE CODE THAT MAKES CANVAS BACKGROUND ROTATE LEFT.
                $("#rotateLeft").click(function() { 
                    $('.canvas').css({
                        "transform":"rotate(-90deg)"
                                });
                    }
                ) //addClass("left")

                //THIS IS THE CODE THAT MAKES CANVAS BACKGROUND ROTATE RIGHT.
                $("#rotateRight").click(function() {
                    $('.canvas').css({
                            "transform":"rotate(0deg)"
                                });
                    }
                )



                //TRYING TO MAKE CANVAS ANNOTABLE.

                //ALL MOUSE LISTENERS ARE SET HERE.
                canvas.onmousedown = function (e) //WHEN MOUSE IS CLICKED
                {
                    canvas.isDrawing = true;

                }

                canvas.onmouseup = function (e) //WHEN MOUSE CLICK IS RELEASED
                {
                    canvas.isDrawing = false;

                }

                canvas.onmousemove = function(e)
                {

                    var res = document.getElementById('result');
                    res.innerHTML = e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY;

                    if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
                       return;
                    }

                    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                    var radius = 5; // or whatever
                    var fillColor = '#ff0000';
                    context.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
                }

                context.fillCircle = function (x, y, radius, fillColor)
                {
                    //alert("fillCircle is here...");
                    this.fillStyle = fillColor;
                    this.beginPath();
                    this.moveTo(x, y);
                    this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                    this.fill();
                }
            });

            function resize_img(val) 
        {
            context.save();
            var width = globalElement_width;
            var height = globalElement_height;
            var zoom_percen = (height * 1); // Maximum zoom 50%
            var ASPECT = 10;//zoom_percen / 30;
            var zoom_value = val / .5;
            var size = width + ASPECT * zoom_value;
            var d = ASPECT*zoom_value/10;          

            $img = $('.canvas');
            $img.stop(true).animate({
            marginTop: -d,
            marginLeft: -d,
            width: size,
            height: size
            }, 250);
            context.restore();

        }
    </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do this for background image
if u want to do zoom in and zoom out for image means [check this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803733/html5-canvas-smoothzoom/14807597#14807597)

it may help u

Comment: Thank You, but it is not a background image. I want to set a background image and want to zoom it.

Comment: have you check the the link which i posted

Comment: Yes, I've seen the page you've posted. Also tested zooming the image having ear-ring and circle on forehead. I hope you wanted to show the same thing.

Comment: <body background="../../Content/themes/base/images/background_default.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;"></body>
u can use this tag for background image

Comment: no i just poted that link so that u can understand the code and u can try in ur program with different elements

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank You. But I want to zoom on the background image of 'canvas'. I'm not trying to set the background property of 'body tag'. I want to set the background of canvas and be able to zoom in & out using a slider.